# Phonegap x aplicação nativa

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile

Phonegap x aplicação nativa: Quais são as principais vantagens e desvantagens das duas.

Comment: As vantagens e desvantagens vão depender totalmente do que você precisa fazer.

Comment: Essa pergunta não é principalmente baseada em opiniões, é perfeitamente possível comparar ambas as abordagens objetivamente. E a comparação é útil - já que o enorme benefício da portabilidade do Phonegap precisa ser pesado contra suas desvantagens, para que se tome uma decisão informada quanto a usá-lo ou não ao desenvolver uma nova aplicação.

Comment: O @Fernando, inclusive, fez um artigo sobre isso. Não sei se posso postar o link aqui. Sugiro que você veja com ele no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) sobre isso.

Answer (score 7):

## Desenvolvimento com: *PhoneGap*

---

O `PhoneGap` é um *framework* para o desenvolvimento de aplicações *híbridas*, utilizando as mais recentes tecnologias da *web*. Bastante conhecidas por *webDevelopers*, que são: *HTML5*, *CSS3* e *javaScript*.

Ele é um *framework* totalmente compatível com outros *frameworks*, que são responsáveis pela user-*interface*, como o *jQuery Mobile*.

### Vantagens

> > - Facilidade para manipular componentes nativos da plataforma.
> > - Facilidade para desenvolver um único código para várias plataformas.
> > - Facilidade no aprendizado, não sendo necessário aprender a linguagem da plataforma.
> > - O aprendizado é ainda mais facilitado para quem já é um web*Developer*.
> > - Compatibilidade com outros *frameworks*.
> > - Framework open-*source*

### Desvantagens

> > - É apenas recomendado para aplicações de pequeno e médio porte.
> > - Péssima performance
> > - Desenvolvimento de *interfaces* é complicado
> > - Péssima usabilidade

---

## Desenvolvimento com: código *nativo*

De um modo geral, o desenvolvimento com código *nativo*, é o mais recomendado para todos os *desenvolvedores*. Ele lhe permite um maior acesso à todas as ferramentas da plataforma e, também, um melhor controle da sua aplicação. Todavia, tem suas desvantagens, que serão citadas logo abaixo.

### Vantagens

> > - Enorme documentação.
> > - Ótima usabilidade.
> > - Ótima performance.
> > - Organização de código mais *avançada*.
> > - Criação de interfaces é facilitada (depende da plataforma).
> > - Segurança.
> > - Comunidade ativa.
> > - Recomendado para aplicações de pequeno, médio e grande porte.
> > - Fácil acesso à funcionalidades do dispositivo (como sensores).
> > - Aplicações que utilizam recursos *2D*/*3D* são mais rápidas, comparando-a *phoneGap*.

### Desvantagens

> > - É necessário aprender a linguagem exigida pela plataforma (Java, C#, Swift, ...).
> > - Código *não portável* para outras plataformas, sendo necessário 1 código para cada.

---

## Batalha de gigantes

Desenvolver *nativamente* é uma boa opção, mesmo sendo necessário que você aprenda uma nova tecnologia. Ainda assim, aprender uma nova tecnologia sempre será bom pra você. Porém, se você não se importa muito com isso e, também não se importa com usabilidade ou performance da aplicação, o uso do *phoneGap* é *recomendado*. Caso contrário, desenvolver nativamente é a melhor opção. O ruim do *phoneGap* é que a performance do aplicativo é bem ruim comparado à um nativo. Mas de qualquer maneira, se sua aplicação não é tão complexa, você pode fazer ela com `phoneGap`. Ou se preferir, pode fazer `nativamente`, e ter um maior controle sobre sua aplicação na plataforma que está desenvolvendo.

---

## Veredito final

No momento, desenvolver **nativamente** continua sendo a melhor opção para desenvolvedores. Mas com o grande avanço tecnológico, quem sabe isso não mude?

Comment: Obrigado. Ouvi o que queria

Answer (score 0):

Veja o seguinte artigo comparando Aplicativos Nativos e Híbridos vantagens e desvantagens:

[Artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/aplicacoes-moveis-nativas-ou-web/30392)

Caso deseje desenvolver aplicativos híbridos eu indicaria a você o  [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), ele utiliza Javascript, CSS3 e HTML, tem por base o Phonegap tem uma boa documentação e muitos plugins na internet para serem utilizados.