# Desenvolvimento multiplataforma mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone, app

Sou programador Java e preciso iniciar no desenvolvimento mobile (Android/IOS/Windows Phone) e gostaria de saber qual é o melhor caminho.

Já andei lendo sobre frameworks que você desenvolve em Javascript/HTML e ele converte/constrói o app para o SO escolhido. Ex: Phonegap.

Vi também alguns serviços online de construção. Ex: Appery.io.

Existe algum outro framework para desenvolvimento mobile?

Obs: Não quero ter que desenvolver o mesmo app nas diversas plataformas (Java para Android, Objective-C para IOS, etc)

Comment: Android Studio, da Google

Comment: Se você quer desenvolver para as 3 plataformas o phonegap é a melhor opção. Obs.: Não recomendo esse appery.io, achei muito fraco

Comment: Xamarin é bem interessante, e usa C#.

Comment: @diego-souza Com o Android Studio eu só posso fazer para Android! A intenção é minimizar o esforço.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NilsonUehara**,

Existem diversas opções para realizar o desenvolvimento multiplataforma mobile:

- [PhoneGAP](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)
- [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/pt-br/intel-xdk)
- [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)

Você pode utilizar para o desenvolvimento nessas plataformas:

- HTML
- Angular
- CSS
- Jquery
- JavaScript
- NodeJS

Temos também o [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) onde o desenvolvimento é feito em C# e a criação das telas pode ser feito através do [Xamarin.Forms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/)

Porém é necessário analisar alguns pontos antes de começar a desenvolver um app hibrido como desempenho, vantagens e desvantagens:

Aqui no SOpt temos uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53473/10315) do @array sobre essa questão.

Comment: O Phonegap/Cordova me parece ser um bom caminho no momento. Pelo que consegui absorver das pesquisas, ele faz a ponte entre o aplicativo desenvolvido em JS e o ambiente nativo (Android/IOS/Windows Phone).